# Catching Custom Exception from OKHTTP Interceptor in Kotlin Flow android

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-flow

I am trying to catch custom exception in my case it is UserUnAuthorizedException, i am trying to throw from OkHttp interceptor and catching in Kotlin Flow, and in catch block i am able to catch this exception

> java.io.IOException: canceled due to
> UserUnAuthorizedException

But app is Crashing, I am unable to understand why this is happening, below is my code

```
suspend fun execute(): Flow<Resource<AccessToken>> = flow {
    emit(Resource.Loading)

    try {
        val loginData = iApi.authorizations(AuthRequestModel().generate())
        emit(Resource.Success(loginData))
    } catch (e: UserUnAuthorizedException) {
        emit(Resource.Error(e))
    }


}
```

**OkHttp Interceptor**

```
 val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    .addInterceptor { chain  ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val response = chain.proceed(request)
                when (response.code()) {
                    401 ->
                        throw UserUnAuthorizedException(app.resources.getString(R.string.invalid_credential))
                }
                response
            }
```

Comment: Exception suggests the `UserUnAuthorizedException` has been wrapped into `java.lang.IOException`, try catching that.

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem, my man? I am having the exact same problem

Comment: Yes, Please Explain your issue